# JFrame not updating when I switch component's position

Tags: java, swing, game-physics

PS : Here is the GitHub for those intrested https://github.com/Yasakidev/AnimalRescueUP/tree/master

I'm developing a "Pet Rescue Saga" Java game in Swing. I'm kind of new to Swing and fell into a problem.

I want my pieces to fall when they are removed. Here I've managed to "remove them" by changing their color but then I want them to fall like a tetris.

Here's my code :

GRID (Which is the JFrame and a singleton class)

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Grid extends JFrame {
    private static Grid main;
    private Case[][] cases;

    public Grid() {
        this.cases = new Case[8][8];
        for (int i = 0; i < cases.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cases[i].length; j++) {
                this.cases[i][j] = new Case(i, j);
                this.add(cases[i][j]);
            }
        }
        this.setSize(800, 800);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public Case getCase(int i, int j) {
        return this.cases[i][j];
    }

    public static Grid getGrid() {
        if(main == null) main = new Grid();
        return main;
    }

    public void swap(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        Case temp = this.cases[x1][y1];
        cases[x1][y1] = cases[x2][y2];
        cases[x2][y2] = temp;
    }

    public void rebuild() {
        for(int i = cases.length-1-1; i > 0; i--) {
            for (int j = cases[i].length-1-1; j > 0; j--) {
                int k = i;
                while(!cases[k+1][j].isActive()) {
                    this.swap(i, j, i+1, j);
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
        //swap(5,5,5,6);
    }
}
```

CASE (Which defines the blocks inside the Grid, on click, they run clicked() and remove all adjacent Blocks of the same color recursively)

```java
import utils.RandomGen;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;

public class Case extends JPanel {
    private JButton btn;
    private Color color;
    private final int posX;
    private final int posY;

    private boolean isActive;

    public Case(int x, int y) {
        //Init Members
        this.posX = x;
        this.posY = y;

        //Init Components
        this.initColor();
        this.initButton();
        this.initPanel();
    }

    public void clicked() {
        this.setVisible(false);
        this.isActive = false;
        checkAdjacent();
        Grid.getGrid().rebuild;
    }

    private void initColor() {
        int i = RandomGen.get(0,4);
        switch(i) {
            case 0 -> this.color = new Color(255,0,0);
            case 1 -> this.color = new Color(0,0, 255);
            case 2 -> this.color = new Color(136, 0, 255);
            case 3 -> this.color = new Color(27, 255, 0);
            default -> this.color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    private void initButton() {
        this.btn = new JButton();
        this.btn.setOpaque(false);
        this.btn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        this.btn.setBorderPainted(false);
        this.btn.addActionListener(new ClickEventHandler(this));
    }

    private void initPanel() {
        this.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0,0,0)));
        this.setBackground(this.color);
        this.add(btn);
        this.setLayout(new CardLayout());
        this.isActive = true;
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void checkAdjacent() {
        //CLEAR DOWN
        if(this.posX != 7 && Grid.getGrid().getCase(this.posX+1, this.posY).isActive && Grid.getGrid().getCase(this.posX+1, this.posY).getColor().getRGB() == this.color.getRGB()) Grid.getGrid().getCase(this.posX+1, this.posY).clicked();
        //CLEAR UP
        if(this.posX != 0 && Grid.getGrid().getCase(this.posX-1, this.posY).isActive && Grid.getGrid().getCase(this.posX-1, this.posY).getColor().getRGB() == this.color.getRGB()) Grid.getGrid().getCase(this.posX-1, this.posY).clicked();
        //CLEAR RIGHT
        if(this.posY != 7 && Grid.getGrid().getCase(this.posX, this.posY+1).isActive && Grid.getGrid().getCase(this.posX, this.posY+1).getColor().getRGB() == this.color.getRGB()) Grid.getGrid().getCase(this.posX, this.posY+1).clicked();
        //CLEAR LEFT
        if(this.posY != 0 && Grid.getGrid().getCase(this.posX, this.posY-1).isActive && Grid.getGrid().getCase(this.posX, this.posY-1).getColor().getRGB() == this.color.getRGB()) Grid.getGrid().getCase(this.posX, this.posY-1).clicked();
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public int getPosX() {
        return posX;
    }

    public int getPosY() {
        return posY;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
    }
}
```

Here's two screenshots of the problem
[Randomly generated grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkCCO.png)

[When clicking on the red pattern for example, i want the rest of the blocks to fall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA4aK.png)

I tried the Grid.rebuild() to make the blocks fall, but nothing changes on the display.

Also if you spot bad habits or mistakes please point them to me.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I assume that you want to add animation to your game. If so, then I refer you to [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: So you recommand I remake the game but with Graphics class and paintComponent instead of this implementation ?

Comment: In order to get animation into a _Swing_ application, you need to perform custom painting. The only way I know of to perform custom painting is to extend class `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent` method. If you just want to automatically change the colors of the squares in your grid over time without having to move them around the screen, then just create a _Swing_ timer. When the colors change it will give the impression that there is movement. By the way, have you considered JavaFX? It has a richer API for animation.

Comment: I can't get your code to compile.

Comment: @Abra Yeah I was afraid this was needed. It's for a school project so I need Swing. Thanks !

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I have a github on it : https://github.com/Yasakidev/AnimalRescueUP/tree/master